# Mail command in linux

Tags: email, sendmail, mail-command

Want to send mail to my email id, but I'm not able to send. I have done 
`sudo apt install mailutils`. Here is my code:

```
ssmtp name@gmail.com
Hello world
```

Showing error

```
ssmtp :cannot open mail 25
```

Answer (score 4):

`ssmtp` (which looked installed on your system as an MTA) is not a fully functional SMTP server.

Instead it relies on an external SMTP server to forward mails to.

The error message you met means that you haven't configured it.

Usually, configuration for `ssmtp` is under `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` (see the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf) for how to use this file).

The most important parameter to set in this configuration file is `mailhub`. Set it to `<your FAI SMTP server>:25` and it shall work.